# Custom People Search URL not working in multiple locations

Tags: search, my-site, search-scope

SharePoint 2010. When in my sites (profiles) the find people box goes to /SearchCenter/Pages/PeopleResults.aspx. I have a custom search based on a web part (searches our HR database not sharepoint users) /SearchCenter/Pages/EmployeeSearch.aspx

Also related if I use the employee search scope on my main page it goes to /SearchCenter/Pages/EmployeeSearch.aspx but if I use it from the drop down in all sites search it goes to /SearchCenter/Pages/results.aspx?k=joe&s=Employees Any way to get the scopes to use the defined "Target results page" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the various search pages and edit the search box web part configuration. In the Miscellaneous section of the web part configuration you can enter the URL for the target search results page.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of the search center URL in the My Sites configuration of the User Profile Service Application.   You can also set this at a site collection level for other site collections.  If you want a certain scope to always go to a certain URL, you can always override the search center URL for that scope in the Search Service Application.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default results page attribute on the People Scope in the SSA. By default it goes to PeopleResults.aspx. You can change that.